# C++ static class variable initialization

Tags: c++

```
#include<string>
class abc
{
  public:
    static const abc PENDING;
  private:
    static const string PENDING_STATUS_CD;
    abc ( const string& iStatus )
    {
      //...........
      Logintodatabase();
      //.............
      logoutfromdatabase();
    }
};
const string abc::PENDING_STATUS_CD  = "P";
const abc abc::PENDING ( abc::PENDING_STATUS_CD );
```

at calling of line const abc abc::PENDING ( abc::PENDING_STATUS_CD ); will call constructor?

Comment: First of all, you'd have to initialize the string before that.

Comment: now please have a look.

Comment: Q: Will it call constructor? A: Yes. it will. What do you see as a potential problem?

Answer (score 0):

Define your `PENDING_STATUS_CD` outside of the class definition. Your current implementation creates a static instance variable witch doesn't make sense.. Statics are by definition not instance variables..Anyway, try that and see what happens.